# Informix return "Routine (%s) can not be resolved" error with IfxCallableStatement

Tags: informix

In my web application, I call an Informix routine with an **`IfxCallableStatement`**.

In this object, all data for procedure parameters are present and of the right type.

This call is functional on all my environment excepted on one environment where the message "`Routine (%s) can not be resolved`" is returned.

All environments have the same application and the same Informix instance structure.

I don't understand why on this machine especially, the routine is not found. Almost, the routine name is not returned but there is "`%s`". Do you know why?

I have checked the procedure on the instance (declaration, number and type of arguments, grants, sysprocauth ...) but all is right and identical to the other environments.

Comment: There's no code here, so there's very little we can do to help you.  Please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name

Comment: %s just means the placeholder in the error message didn't work. It should have inserted the routine name.  So a defect in the message output is all.

Comment: Jonathan, I realize how little material is available to you. I apologize, but it is complicated to describe all the kinematics of an application's procedure call.

This is a very strange behavior because all procedure calls are executed the same in the application using a utility (java package) and only one procedure does not work (all other calls from others procedures are correctly interpreted and executed).

I am trying to get the informix logs to know if the name of the procedure is in the entry of the call

Comment: Try getting a SQLIDEBUG trace (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-enable-jdbc-tracing-starting-jdbc-version-30x) 
It may help you to understand what's different with that specific SPL.

Comment: I had tried to generate it but don't know what to do with generated file. Is there a utility to read it?